# Shell script - blanks are not always recognized as such?

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, newlines, output

I'm confused on how bash interprets blanks while executing a script.
In the end, I want a script that is fed by a csv file containing software used by an organisation and it should return the CVEs for these programs, by calling a python script to fetch this information.

My file would look this, but with over 500 lines:

```
"CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008";"SAP";"reporting software";;"Mr. Smith"
```

And is fed to my script like

```
$ getcve.sh < test.csv
```

When I run this small script I get strange results concerning the wordcount (which I wanted to use to loop through the python script's output to store in another file):

```
Read from file
Source: CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032 
Words in variable: 2
CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032 
Words processed: 1
```

However, when I hardcode "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008" in the script, the count changes to what I would expect:

```
 Hardcoded query
 Query: "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008"
 Source: CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032
 Words in variable: 2
 CVE-2010-2590
 CVE-2010-3032
 Words processed: 2
```

The script itself looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Hardcoded query"
query='"SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008"'
echo "Query: "$query
var2=$(python3 $HOME/cve-search/bin/search_fulltext.py -q "$query"  | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "Source: "$var2
i=0
echo "Words in variable: "$(echo "$var2"|wc -w)
for cve in $var2
do
    echo $cve
    i=$[ $i+1 ]
done
echo "Words processed: "$i

echo
echo "Read from file"
IFS_OLD=$IFS
IFS=";"
while read title firm desc version manager
do
    query='"'$(echo $firm $title $version | tr -d '"')'"'
    var3=$(python3 $HOME/cve-search/bin/search_fulltext.py -q "$query" | tr '\n' ' ')
    echo "Source: "$var3
    i=0
    echo "Words in variable: "$(echo "$var3"|wc -w)
    for cve in $var3
    do
        echo $cve
        i=$[ $i+1 ]
    done
    echo "Words processed: "$i
done
IFS=$IFS_OLD
```

Is there a trick or method to get the same results as the hard coded query when reading from a file?

I stumbled onto this by toying a little bit around (shell scripting is new for me) and this weird result is bothering me ^^"

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I think you have a problem of quotes, could you add the line `echo "Query: "$query` before line `var3=...` and post the result?

Comment: Hi @purplepsycho. Thank you for your reply.
The result is the same:

`Hardcoded query
Query: "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008"
Source: CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032
Words in variable: 2
CVE-2010-2590
CVE-2010-3032
Words processed: 2`

`Read from file
Query: "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS 2008"
Source: CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032 
Words in variable: 2
CVE-2010-2590 CVE-2010-3032 
Words processed: 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from `IFS=";"` I think: this modification will have an impact on the for loop.

Try:

```
IFS_OLD=$IFS
IFS=";"
while read title firm desc version manager
do
    query='"'$(echo $firm $title $version | tr -d '"')'"'
    var3=$(python3 $HOME/cve-search/bin/search_fulltext.py -q "$query" | tr '\n' ' ')
    echo "Source: "$var3
    i=0
    echo "Words in variable: "$(echo "$var3"|wc -w)
    IFS=" "
    for cve in $var3
    do
        echo $cve
        i=$[ $i+1 ]
    done
    IFS=";"
    echo "Words processed: "$i
done
IFS=$IFS_OLD
```

Comment: Excellent :D
That solved my problem. I read to be careful when using IFS, but I thought it only applied to file and not so somethings like looping through a variable.
I'll make sure to remember this. Thank you very much @purplepsycho

Comment: ... or don't *change* IFS in the body of the script at all, instead set it explicitly for the `read` command `while IFS=";" read title firm desc version manager`

Comment: That sounds like a much safer way @steeldriver.
What would be a good book to learn shell scripting in a proper way? I'm mostly experimenting and reading small articles on blogs etc.

Comment: @AkiraTakizawa unfortunately there's a lot of so-so scripting advice out there: my go-to for this kind of stuff is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: That's added to my bookmarks (^_^)b

Answer (score 0):

If you place a string with spaces in a variable, then that will expand to *one* value when used like `for i in $var3`. However, when you use `echo $var3` the output will contain the spaces and `wc -w` will count those.

You need to modify your loop to

```
for cve in $(echo $var3)
```

so that the value is re-evaluated and the spaces cause the value to be split up into discrete words.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't change the output. @purplepsycho's solution below did the trick :)